# CSS Menu Bar - is 3 divs necessary?

Tags: css, html

I'm creating a menu bar for my site and I'm wondering if I'm doing this correctly.

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? It just seems excessive to use 3 divs.

Here is how I'm currently handling it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#topbar {
    background: #487BC0;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#links {
    padding: 15px 0 15px 840px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="topbar">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="links">Login | Register</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">Content goes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you wrote that piece yourself, you should know how to shorten/trim it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im no Guru but maybe something like this will work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
background: #487BC0;
width: 100%
min-width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container > span {
display: block;
padding: 15px 0 15px 840px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#content {
position: relative;
background: #f6f6f6;
width: 960px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <span>Login | Register</span>
</div>

<div id="content">Content goes here</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then again, im no Guru O.o

Answer (score 0):

remove the #topbar if you do not want the blue background to stretch otherwise its alright i think..

> There are many solutions to same problem

Answer (score 0):

My Way Of Skinning this cat. The way I see it, width is common so only set it once.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="topBar">Login | Register</div>
   <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 Auto;

}

.topBar
{
    background-color:#487BC0;
    text-align:right;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.topBar div
{
    padding: 15px 0 15px 840px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content
{

    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/V9DGp/